# Use Accept header to remap request URL (api versioning using accept header)

Tags: ocelot

Anyone can suggest a correct place to inject a code in ocelot (a handler or similar) to get a request, look at it and if there is a header "Accept" with version specs add it to the path.
For a header value application/vnd.myapp.v2+json it would signal that we want to call API v2 and adjust request accordingly.
this logic needs to be executed before route rules are applied because downstream routes will have version in the path:

a call GET /teams/ (with accept header application/vnd.myapp.v2+json) becomes
a call GET /v2/teams/ which, using redirect rule will be send to a service that handles teams calls V2.

example logic (need adjustment to add version in the beginnig)

```
 private static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString AppendVersionInPath(DownstreamContext ctx)
        {
            if (ctx.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("accept", out var acceptHeaderValue))
            {
                var resultString = Regex.Match(acceptHeaderValue, @"\d+").Value;
                if (resultString.Length > 0)
                {
                    var versionPath = $"/v{resultString}";
                    ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path = ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString(versionPath));
                }
            }
            return ctx.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some considerations we ended up using .net [rewrite functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0) by implementing pipeline handler that takes request and rewrites URL path based on the header value (if present)

I do not expect this to be the best answer but almost certainly ocelot does not allow such transformation.